# Create calendar from Excel data that automatically updates

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I would like to:

- Create an calendar file based on Excel data (i know how to do
  this)
- Calendar is auto-refreshed in calendar app whenever the Excel file is updated

Is that possible? And what function could I use?

Thanks,

Alex

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Worksheet.Change` Event, it will run when cells on the worksheet are changed by the user or by an external link.

For example( The following code example sets the values in the range A1:A10 to be uppercase as the data is entered into the cell ):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A10")) Is Nothing Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    'Set the values to be uppercase
    Target.Value = UCase(Target.Value)
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

For more information, please refer to this link:

[Worksheet.Change Event (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change)